# sass nested reset with import

Tags: css, sass, reset

My goal is to reset all elements in `#wrapper` div.

How can I do it in **SASS** ?

**Idea:**

```
#wrapper {

    @import url(http://reset5.googlecode.com/hg/reset.min.css);  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how an import looks in Sass:

```
@import "_reset";
```

The file can be either .scss, .sass or .css. It must be on your local file system; the `@import` must point to a location relative to the file you are using it in. The underscore is a partial, which means that it will only be included in other files, and won't output its own reset.css file.

You'll probably find it easiest to save a local copy of that reset file. Consider making changes to your reset copy - there's little sense to resetting `#wrapper body`.

Also note that if you want to affect just `#wrapper`, you'll do this:

```
#wrapper {
    @import "_reset";
}
```

But if you want to affect everything inside `#wrapper`, you'll do this:

```
#wrapper * {
    @import "_reset";
}
```